# Why are flutter constraints are not pushed down through the widget tree?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Refer to the attached Widget Tree.

I am expecting that the constraints set in the ConstrainedBox will be pushed down to the entire sub-tree. However... somewhere along the way... the height constraint goes missing!

Can anyone explain why this is happening? And how do I enforce that the constraints be applied to the tree?

(PS: Stack and Align subtree - sure I can understand that... but what about the rest?)

[image]

```
$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H15 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.4 at /Users/agautam/tools/flutter
    • Framework revision 1aafb3a8b9 (2 weeks ago), 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800
    • Engine revision 2c956a31c0
    • Dart version 2.10.4

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/agautam/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/agautam/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.2, Build version 12B45b
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 11 Pro (mobile) • 70B5851E-D6FE-4D5F-8703-D9AEB22DE51E • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-2 (simulator)
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter docs has a couple of awesome articles to understand Layout and constraints.

1] https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints

> Constraints go down. Sizes go up. Parent sets position.
> =======================================================
>
> Flutter layout can’t really be understood without knowing this rule,
> so Flutter developers should learn it early on.
>
> In more detail:
>
> • A widget gets its own constraints from its parent. A constraint is
> just a set of 4 doubles: a minimum and maximum width, and a minimum
> and maximum height.
>
> • Then the widget goes through its own list of children. One by one, the
> widget tells its children what their constraints are (which can be
> different for each child), and then asks each child what size it wants
> to be.
>
> • Then, the widget positions its children (horizontally in the x axis,
> and vertically in the y axis), one by one.
>
> • And, finally, the widget tells its parent about its own size (within
> the original constraints, of course).
>
> Example 23
>
> ```
> Row(
>    children:[
>       Container(color: Colors.red, child: Text('Hello!')),
>       Container(color: Colors.green, child: Text('Goodbye!')),
>    ]
> )
> ```
>
> The screen forces the Row to be exactly the same size as the screen.
>
> Just like an UnconstrainedBox, the Row won’t impose any constraints
> onto its children, and instead lets them be any size they want. The
> Row then puts them side-by-side, and any extra space remains empty.

2] https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints

> **Unbounded constraints**
>
> In certain situations, the constraint that is given to a box is
> unbounded, or infinite. This means that either the maximum width or
> the maximum height is set to double.INFINITY.
>
> A box that tries to be as big as possible won’t function usefully when
> given an unbounded constraint and, in debug mode, such a combination
> throws an exception that points to this file.
>
> The most common cases where a render box finds itself with unbounded
> constraints are within flex boxes (Row and Column), and within
> scrollable regions (ListView and other ScrollView subclasses).
>
> In particular, ListView tries to expand to fit the space available in
> its cross-direction (for example, if it’s a vertically-scrolling
> block, it tries to be as wide as its parent). If you nest a vertically
> scrolling ListView inside a horizontally scrolling ListView, the inner
> one tries to be as wide as possible, which is infinitely wide, since
> the outer one is scrollable in that direction.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not answer my question. Both the examples you have given don't apply. "Constraints go down" -> I have a set of constraints that don't seem to be going down! So... unbounded constraints / UnconstrainedBox is not applicable here. Please do point out if I missed something specific in your response!

Comment: From what I understand, the children of Column get their unbounded constraints double.INFINITY from their parent, which in this case happens to be the Column. In your case the Column gets its constraints from ConstrainedBox, however the Column passes unbounded constraints to its children. This is also what the Example 23 demonstrates.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation @bluenile

Comment: Please like and accept the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks.

Comment: The problem has been identified, but not yet been solved :) Will definitely accept after I come up with a solution. Thanks again